# Android wake screen method

Tags: android, xposed-framework

My friend and I are trying to develop a module for Xposed Framework that hooks the method called when you press the home button and the screen wakes up.
We have searched around, trying to find some viable information, but we need help understanding how you would proceed to find this method and hook it (and use exposed to run some code before the wake method is ran).
We are using API 15 (Android 4.0.3).

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same and found the `android.os.IPowerManager.wakeUp(long)` method. I haven't tried it myself yet, but I guess this is what you're looking for. I found it within API22, but as a basic system method it should be there in API14 as well, just look around there .